# Complex regular expression - alphanumeric, hyphen-space-hyphen, + and ++

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression supporting alphanumeric, hyphen, hyphen-space-hyphen, + and ++.

For the alphanumeric with hyphen, space and plus, I can give something like `/^[a-zA-Z0-9- +]*$/`. Can I use `+{0,2}` inside the square bracket?

Anybody please help me to complete my required regular expression.

Comment: Please give some example input strings and expected result.

Comment: Examples of input strings are abc-123++, abc- -123, abc+ etc.

Comment: Are these strings supose to match? What about `---+++abc-------+`? Please, edit yur question and give some strings that must match and some that must not.

Comment: +++ is not supported. All i need to support is [a-zA-Z0-9- +], but + is +{0,2}. Also space is only need to support in between hyphens, ie.(-\s-).

Comment: Is `++` a valid string? Give examples of valid and invalid strings and why they are valid or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```regex
^(\+{0,2}[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\+{0,2}$
```

It will accept `+ab`, `++ab`, `++ab++`, `++ab++a+`, etc., but it will not accept `+++a`, `++ab+++`, etc.

Comment: Now I need to support the hyphen-space-hyphen along with this. Any way thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: Below regular expression is a reduced one and will accept strings which contain single +, double + (but not +++, ++++, etc), hyphen and hyphen-space-hyphen (and combination of these)

 
^(?!.*\+{3,})(\+{0,2}(-\s-)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)*$